# Date from String is not giving correct date

Tags: ios, string, date, swift4, nsdateformatter

I want to set "EST" as the default time zone for every user, but there is one condition that needs to be check in the current date at 7:45 PM. So I am comparing two dates, but the problem is when I convert the current Date to String it gives me the correct EST time, when I convert that String again to Date in EST it gives me time 4 hours ahead of EST. Here is the code for conversion

```
class func getCurrentDateTime() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    print(dateString)

    let convertDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    convertDateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    convertDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
    let currentDate = convertDateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    print(currentDate)

    let comparedDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    comparedDateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    comparedDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
    let comparedDate = comparedDateFormatter.date(from: "\(currentDate) 19:45:00")
    print(comparedDate)

    let currentDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    currentDateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    comparedDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "EST")
    let currentDateAndTime = currentDateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    print(currentDateAndTime)

    return dateString
```

}

Comment: Both dateString and comparedDate are showing their values in UTC. There is an offset of 4 hrs between EST and UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a date does not have a time zone.
So when I use a dateFormatter to convert a date to a string representation of the string will reflect the time zone the dateFormatter is set to.
But when you use the same formatter to convert the the string back into a date the date would not have the the time zone offset anymore.
So this sounds to me as if it is working properly.

Edit:
So if you are trying to compare two dates I would do something like:

```
let date1 = Date()
let date2 = Date().addingTimeInterval(100)

if date1 == date2 {
   // dates are exactly equal
} else if date1 > date2 {
  // date1 is the most recent
} else if date1 < date2 {
  // date2 is the most recent
}
```

And if I were trying to display these dates I would use the date formatter to convert them to strings.

Comment: So how can I calculate the exact time in EST zone. Should I have to subtract 4hours from date.

Comment: You should not have to subtract time manually, I edited my answer hopefully it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code as you requested:

```
func getCurrentDateTime() -> String {
    var checkString : String!
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a"

    let dateString:String! = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter1.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
    dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

    let dateString1:String! = dateFormatter1.string(from: Date())
    let convertDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    convertDateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    convertDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")

    let currentDateformat = convertDateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    let compareDate = "\(currentDateformat) 07:45:00 PM"
    let compareDate1 = "\(currentDateformat) 07:45:00"

    if  dateString == compareDate {
        checkString = "equal date"
    }
    if dateString1 < compareDate1{
         checkString = "greater than"
    } else {
    checkString = "less than"
    }
    return checkString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func getCurrentDateTime() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

    let convertDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    convertDateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    convertDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
    let currentDate = convertDateFormatter.string(from: Date())

    let comparedDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    comparedDateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    let comparedDate = comparedDateFormatter.date(from: "\(currentDate) 19:45:00")

    let currentDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    currentDateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    let currentDateAndTime = currentDateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

    return dateString

}
```

Plesae check this code .

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't find anything wrong with the code.

The `Date` always be in UTC timezone. The DateFormatter did the magic.

To print Date in as per the format:
use `string(from:)` method.

```
if let currentDateAndTime = currentDateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    print(currentDateFormatter.string(from: currentDateAndTime))
}
```

> NB: When working with fixed format dates, such as RFC 3339, you set
>   the dateFormat property to specify a format string. For most fixed
>   formats, you should also set the locale property to a POSIX locale
>   ("en_US_POSIX"), and set the timeZone property to UTC.